# How to set preselected tab

Tags: angular, tabs, selected, ng-class

I have this setup in html and I'm usign Angular 2. I wonder if there is any way that, on refresh page, one of tab can be preselected and be open, or must I set that in other way. thanks[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: make use of viewChild and set the class to open for the pre selected tab, also please try and post code instead of image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the code on init in the component as-

```
ngOnInit() {
 tab = 1;
}
```

Comment: I had to do this ..."private tab;"  in class, and then "this.tab=1;" in ngInInit ...and that solve my problem ...thanks, this was enough for me to do it ;)